# Wireguard on Windows: Unable to set interface addresses, routes, dns,

Tags: wireguard

I have installed Wireguard on Windows 7-32bit
And set the config:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = *********
Address = 172.22.2.2/24
DNS = 172.22.2.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = *******
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = ******:8755
PersistentKeepalive = 45
```

Pretty sure that the DNS setting does not matter, since I have '#' it and set it to '8.8.8.8' while everything the same.
AllowedIPs neither matters since it was set as '172.22.2.1' & '172.22.2.1/24'

It did connect at first, but quickly fails. The pop-up sugguest everything goes wrong from

> Unable to set interface addresses, routes, dns, and/or interface settings

Here is the entire log for a single trial of connection:

```
2020-10-11 14:00:12.436200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Starting WireGuard/0.1.1 (Windows 6.1.7601; 386)
2020-10-11 14:00:12.437200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Watching network interfaces
2020-10-11 14:00:12.445200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Resolving DNS names
2020-10-11 14:00:12.445200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Creating Wintun interface
2020-10-11 14:00:13.938200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Warning: unable to determine Wintun version: The system cannot find the file specified.
2020-10-11 14:00:13.939200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Enabling firewall rules
2020-10-11 14:00:13.998200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Dropping privileges
2020-10-11 14:00:13.998200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Creating interface instance
2020-10-11 14:00:13.999200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.000200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.001200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.001200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.001200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: event worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.002200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: TUN reader - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.003200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.004200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.004200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.004200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.004200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.004200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Setting interface configuration
2020-10-11 14:00:14.005200: [TUN] [OneVPS] UAPI: Updating private key
2020-10-11 14:00:14.005200: [TUN] [OneVPS] UAPI: Removing all peers
2020-10-11 14:00:14.006200: [TUN] [OneVPS] UAPI: Transition to peer configuration
2020-10-11 14:00:14.006200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - UAPI: Created
2020-10-11 14:00:14.006200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - UAPI: Updating endpoint
2020-10-11 14:00:14.007200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - UAPI: Updating persistent keepalive interval
2020-10-11 14:00:14.008200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - UAPI: Removing all allowedips
2020-10-11 14:00:14.008200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - UAPI: Adding allowedip
2020-10-11 14:00:14.008200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Bringing peers up
2020-10-11 14:00:14.015200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: receive incoming IPv6 - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.016200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: receive incoming IPv4 - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.016200: [TUN] [OneVPS] UDP bind has been updated
2020-10-11 14:00:14.016200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Starting...
2020-10-11 14:00:14.016200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Routine: sequential receiver - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.016200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Routine: nonce worker - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.017200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Routine: sequential sender - started
2020-10-11 14:00:14.017200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Sending keepalive packet
2020-10-11 14:00:14.017200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Monitoring default v6 routes
2020-10-11 14:00:14.017200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Sending handshake initiation
2020-10-11 14:00:14.018200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Binding v6 socket to interface 23 (blackhole=false)
2020-10-11 14:00:14.019200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Awaiting keypair
2020-10-11 14:00:14.019200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Setting device v6 addresses
2020-10-11 14:00:14.418200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Monitoring default v4 routes
2020-10-11 14:00:14.418200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Binding v4 socket to interface 23 (blackhole=false)
2020-10-11 14:00:14.419200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Setting device v4 addresses
2020-10-11 14:00:14.546200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Listening for UAPI requests
2020-10-11 14:00:14.546200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Startup complete
2020-10-11 14:00:14.546200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Unable to set interface addresses, routes, dns, and/or interface settings: runNetsh run - exit status 1
2020-10-11 14:00:14.664200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Device closing
2020-10-11 14:00:14.664200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: TUN reader - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.311200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: event worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.311200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: receive incoming IPv4 - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.311200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: receive incoming IPv6 - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.311200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.311200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Stopping...
2020-10-11 14:00:15.311200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.312200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.312200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.312200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.312200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.313200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: handshake worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: encryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.314200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Routine: decryption worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.315200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Routine: nonce worker - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.315200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Routine: sequential receiver - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.315200: [TUN] [OneVPS] peer(WrUw…B4VY) - Routine: sequential sender - stopped
2020-10-11 14:00:15.315200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Interface closed
2020-10-11 14:00:15.315200: [TUN] [OneVPS] Shutting down
```

Answer (score 2):

This won't apply to your case according to your configs, but i ran into the exact same behavior and thought maybe someone else could use my solution:
After testing a lot of different things (reactivating IPv6, building the client from scratch, running with different users, multiple reboots, etc), it turned out that **the windows client doesn't seem to like MTU values in the tunnel config**. Simply removing that entry solved this issue for me, so perhaps if you remove the keepalive, it will solve it.